# redis - compare 10 million sets with each other

Tags: redis, nosql

This is the setup that I have going on:

[domain:id] => [keyword_id, keyword_id2, keyword_id3....]
....

What I want to do is for each domain, find other similar domains that contain similar keywords. The way I "measure" similarity between domain:1 and domain:2, for example, is by dividing intersection(domain:1, domain:2) by union(domain:1, domain:2).

The problem is that I have about 5 million domains with each having about a couple hundred keywords on average. Doing this similarity calculation in a nested loop comparing each domain with every other domain would take years on the hardware I have now. I tested this just for one domain:

```
keys = redis.keys("domain:*");

foreach(keys as key){
    long inter = sinterstore("inter_temp", "domain:1", key);
     long union = sunionstore("union_temp", "domain:1", key);

    float similarity = inter / union;

    if(similarity > 0.1){
       similar_domains.add(key);
    }
}
```

...

^ and computing similar domains for just this one domain took about 2 minutes. Doing this for 5 million domains would have taken years.

So what could I do? I have no problem moving this program to the most expensive Amazon EC2 instance for an hour once a week to compute it all, and send it back to my host, but would that even help or do I simply have too much data?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing each domain one by one. can't you create a batch of say 100 and pass all the keys in that domain to Redis where it will do the union/intersection for you.

For example

```
SADD domain:1   a b c d e f 
SADD domain:2   a   c   e
SADD domain:3   c   e   f   h

SINTERSTORE destination domain:1 domain:2 domain:3  
             will result following keys [a, b ,c ,d ,e ,f, h] in destination set
and 

SINTERSTORE  destination domain:1 domain:2 domain:3   
              will result following keys [c ,e] in destination set
```